# Replace emoticons with emoji

Tags: javascript, emoji, emoticons

I've some text, that may include text emoticons (eg: `;)`, `:(`). I'd like to replace these with their corresponding emoji unicode characters ( and ) for the above example.

My intention is to then run twimoji on this text.

I know I can find-and-replace, but I'd rather use something already pre-build that does this already.

Any libraries that already implement this? I believe that the list of common emoticons is the largest bit of work here.

Comment: https://github.com/kof/emoticons

Comment: @OddDev I don't think that library replaces text emoticons with unicode characters.

Comment: @Moogs and it would be a pain to invest these 5 minutes to let it do so?

Comment: @OddDev It looks like you have to manually define a list of all the emoticons (which is want to avoid doing), and it replaces them with images. There's nothing of use for me there.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's already a library out there that turns text emoticons to unicode characters but here's an example of how you could possibly implement it yourself.

```
 var map = {
   "<3": "\u2764\uFE0F",
   "</3": "\uD83D\uDC94",
   ":D": "\uD83D\uDE00",
   ":)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
   ";)": "\uD83D\uDE09",
   ":(": "\uD83D\uDE12",
   ":p": "\uD83D\uDE1B",
   ";p": "\uD83D\uDE1C",
   ":'(": "\uD83D\uDE22"
 };

 function escapeSpecialChars(regex) {
   return regex.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1');
 }

 document.getElementById('textarea').oninput = function() {
   for (var i in map) {
     var regex = new RegExp(escapeSpecialChars(i), 'gim');
     this.value = this.value = this.value.replace(regex, map[i]);
   }
 };
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/04zv3ozh/18/**

Comment: The `\uFE0F`at the heart causes a second invisible Unicode char to be added — I have to hit backspace twice to delete the heart. Basically it’s not necessary.

Comment: I understand that it's as stupid-simple as running `regex.replace`. My question pointed more towards an already-done solution, or a complete table or emotions I can use, instead of manually listing them myself maintaining this listing.

Comment: Maybe use `oninput` instead of `onkeyup`

Comment: A full list of ascci emojis can be found here https://github.com/needim/wdt-emoji-bundle/blob/master/emoji.js#L1846

Answer (score 2):

you can use this npm package that provide also a map of smiles and respective emoticons:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/smile2emoji