# Replace ":)" with smiley icon inside input

Tags: php, input

I want to make when i type ":)" inside input, that smiley will automaticly convert to icon. I have all icons in parseSmiley($text); and i don't know how to implement this into input form.

Convert this - [Image OLD][[image]
To this - [Image NEW][[image]

I tryed something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="parseSmiley(message)" id="message" autocomplete="off" maxlength="300" style="width: 100%;" />
```

But it's not working...

Comment: You sure php is the correct tool for this?

Comment: use javascript, using php for this task is like hammering in a nail with the blunt end of a screwdriver :)

Comment: @MarcHolman Any example?

Comment: My javascript is rusty but I think you could set up an onclick event handler for the button then inside the javascript function it calls test for the string you're looking for and use document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML = "(your html/css for the icon)" .  W3Schools is a great reference for the implementation details.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935513/replace-emoticons-with-emoji)

Comment: @GerritFries Can i use [link](http://jsfiddle.net/04zv3ozh/22/) instead and how?